# Can connection resiliency cause problems?

Tags: database, entity-framework

EF has a feature of [connection resiliency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx). Our legacy code has its own mechanism for the same purpose. It's a widespread practice to retry failed operation several times.

Now consider the following case:

Concurrency check is off, and connection is lost immediately after server commits transaction, but before it sends acknowledgement of commitment.
Does it mean that after restoring connection *in order to avoid duplicated transaction* we need to ask SQL server whether transaction with given identity is successfully commited?

Comment: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20of%20Transaction%20Commit%20Failures

Comment: @GertArnold Nice, thanks. Exactly what I need.